# Search a value in other sheet to match the value selected in a dropdown, EXCEL

Tags: excel, ms-office, spreadsheet

Inside sheet "A" I have a column where I can select a value (dropdown select) from a column of another sheet (Sheet B).

Inside Sheet "B" I have a second column with a value related to the one of the left (A1 and B1 are related).

My problem is that I want to bring value of the second column from the SHEET B into SHEET A aside of the corresponding value selected in the dropdown. Tried the IF function but I didn't realize how to make it work.

**Here some Screnshoots**

**SHEET A:**

[image: SHEET A]

**SHEET B**

[image: SHEET B]

Example: In Sheet A in B3 should be the value of matching to Renault Clio of the Sheet B, and so on.

Comment: Add some sample data or screenshots to understand better

Comment: Hello, done, I just updated the post with screenshoots. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in Cell B3 of Sheet A and copy it down:

=If(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,SheetB!A:B,2,false)),"",VLOOKUP(A3,SheetB!A:B,2,false))

As the name of the car will be stored in Cell A1 after the selection, you can use the lookup to find the corresponding value on Sheet B and then return the second column value.

I have added error checking to make the output look nice if the value is empty or can't be found.

Comment: Thank you, this function "vlookup" is a wonder. This solved! thanks again!